# New to AngularJS: Trying to make a directive and using it via a comment in the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I write the following code

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <input type="text" ng-model="$scope.firstName"">
        <input type="text" ng-model="$scope.lastName">

        <p>{{ $scope.firstName + ' ' + $scope.lastName }}</p>

        <!-- directive: test-directive -->

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.firstName = "Shadab";
            $scope.lastName = "Khan";
        });

        app.directive("testDirective", function() {
            return {
                restrict : "M",
                replace : true,
                template : "Made in a directive"
            };
        });
</script>
```

The directive doesn't seem to work:
[image]
But when I make the following change to the template property, the directive starts working.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
        <input type="text" ng-model="$scope.firstName"">
        <input type="text" ng-model="$scope.lastName">

        <p>{{ $scope.firstName + ' ' + $scope.lastName }}</p>

        <!-- directive: test-directive -->

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.firstName = "Shadab";
            $scope.lastName = "Khan";
        });

        app.directive("testDirective", function() {
        return {
            restrict : "M",
            replace : true,
            template : "<h1>Made by a directive!</h1>"
        };
});


    </script>
```

[image]

I want to know why, just the addition of the h1 tags in the template property, makes the directive to start working?

**Note:** **Ignore the input and p tags, please.**

Comment: There is a link in error stacktrace. Follow it, it explains why. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt?p0=testDirective&p1=

Comment: Thanks for this, this explains the reason behind this. But what exactly is the reason of this being unsupported? Why can't multiple nodes replace a single element? Is the answer to this question related to the DOM tree of the document?

Comment: *"Why can't multiple nodes replace a single element?"*. They can, but Angular team decided that it is not how directive should work. You have one node (directive) which expands to multiple nodes - maybe it's not very logical. But one to one - makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Because it's invalid

You must have a single root element in your template, it can be any element you want. for example

**Invalid template**

```
template : "Made by a directive!"
```

**Valid template**

```
template : "<div>Made by a directive!</div>"
template : "<a>Made by a directive!</a>"
template : "<h2>Made by a directive!</h2>"
```

You can see this error in the console log (open using <kbd>F12</kbd>)

[image]

---

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt?p0=testDirective&p1=

> When a directive is declared with template (or templateUrl) and
>   replace mode on, the template must have exactly one root element. That
>   is, the text of the template property or the content referenced by the
>   templateUrl must be contained within a single html element. For
>   example,
>
> blah *blah* blah
>
> instead of simply blah
>   *blah* blah. Otherwise, the replacement operation would result
>   in a single element (the directive) being replaced with multiple
>   elements or nodes, which is unsupported and not commonly needed in
>   practice.